# how to use InsertService:LoadAsset() with the name of model, not asset id?

Tags: lua, assets, roblox

I am working with the Roblox studio `InsertService:LoadAsset()` API witch can import models, decals, scripts, etc... I am trying to do the same(importing models and decals) just by the name of the model, not the id.

the code form `@darkelementallord` (roblox):

```
local ID = 0000000 --Change this to the model ID
local InsertService = game:GetService("InsertService") --Get the service

local Model = InsertService:LoadAsset(ID) --Insert the model
local NewModel = Model:GetChildren()[1] --Find your model

NewModel.Parent = workspace --Put it into the game
Model:Destroy() --Destroy the container model
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot load an `Asset` with `InsertService` just with the name of the `Asset`.
You need the `AssetId` of the `Asset` to load it.